# Depends on lib32gcc1 , libc6-i386 , can't install neither

Tags: 13.10, dependencies

I tried to install catalyst for my Radeon Graphics on 13.10  , but looks like everything went wrong . Now I can't install any software , and the software center says :
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
fglrx: Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu18 is installed
       Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not installed
       Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not installed
xserver-xorg-video-intel: Depends: xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installed
```

I am a noob , thus I really don't know what to do . I tried to install lib32gcc1 and libc6-i386 via apt-get and it didn''t work also for unmet dependecies .

I downloaded .deb package of libc6-i386 but I couldn't install it. any help ?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to install the 32 bit version on a 64 bit system?

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal window run these commands one by one in order.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this once**

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f update && sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get  -f install libqtcore4"=4:4.5.3" lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 xorg-video-abi-13 xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

After executing these commands if still it shows any error, please mention in your question with the command name. Reply..

Comment: it say -f : command line option -f is not known

Comment: @james: Plz check for extra spaces and try again.

Comment: I have 500 GB free but it still says "-f: Command line option is not known"

Comment: @james: Sorry I mean **Extra blank spaces** in the commands :)

Comment: @SauravKumar There is no -f flag for sudo apt-get combining with update