# Ubuntu 14.04 + nvidia-331-updates makes a blank desktop screen

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I upgraded my installation from 13.10 to 14.04.

The problem is that whenever I install the Nvidia drivers from the GUI, upon reboot or trying to login again it only shows the wallpaper of my desktop and nothing else. The mouse does move around, but nothing works. I am unable to open a terminal or do anything else.

If I go into the tty console and purge the drivers, then things seem to work again. I have an Optimus setup, with an onboard Intel and discrete Nvidia GTX770M card. It's a 64-bit architecture.

I really need to work with CUDA, and was hopeful after hearing that nvidia-prime was released, but this is a real downer. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

[Ubuntu 14.04: nvidia drivers cannot be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451862/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-drivers-cannot-be-installed)

Basically check if your using your local update server or the main one. I finally got mine to at least show Unity after changing the update server to main and reinstall the 331-updates.

You may also want to blacklist the open-source Nvidia Nouveau to avoid conflicts

```
echo "blacklist nouveau" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xorg.conf` file may be the issue. I had to change text inside my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. Specifically, the last lines of this file include text that disables composite graphics.

```
Section "Extensions"
        Option      "Composite"  "Disable"
EndSection
```

I had to comment out those lines for my NVIDIA card to work properly. I did this by adding a pound symbol (`#`) to the beginning of these lines as shown below

```
#Section "Extensions"
#        Option      "Composite"  "Disable"
#EndSection
```

You can modify this file by opening it with an editor as root. The following command is one way to edit this file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Save the file and restart the computer (or restart the login session by logging out).